# Flag or unflag a checkbox depending on the answer given in dialogs (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog, modal-dialog, angularjs-ng-repeat

Purpose: I have a list of checkboxes which shows different forms (to compile) when flagged. The checkboxes make appear a dialog (angular - $mddialog) when you try to unflag them which asks you if you really want to remove the corresponding form. How can I prevent the single checkbox to be unflagged before the user click on "Confirm" or "Cancel"? How can I keep it flagged by selecting Cancel and unflag it by selecting Confirm?

Here's my code:

file.js (containing my angular module, controllers and so on):

```
... //INSIDE controller 'ctrlOne'
$scope.fromService = dialog.deletionConfirmDialog('Title','Wanna remove?');
...
//OUTSIDE controller 'ctrlOne'
...

...
hello.service('dialog', function($mdDialog) {
   this.deletionConfirmDialog = function(title, cont){
        $mdDialog.show($mdDialog.confirm({
            templateUrl: 'deletionConfirmDialog.html',
            title : title,
            textContent : cont,
            ok : 'Confirm',
            cancel: 'Cancel'
        })).then(function() {
             console.log('confirmed');
             //to be completed
        }, function() {
             console.log('abort');
             //to be completed
        });
    }
}
...
```

stepOne.html:

```
...
  <div ng-repeat="item in serv" ng-model="item.active">
      <md-checkbox id="{{item.id}}" aria-label="check" type="checkbox">                      ng-model="item.attivo">
 </div>
...
```

The page stepOne.html is connected to a specific controller ('ctrlOne')

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with the `ng-checked` directive.

You could do something like:

Your service:

```
hello.service('dialog', function($mdDialog, $q) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
   this.deletionConfirmDialog = function(title, cont){
        $mdDialog.show($mdDialog.confirm({
            templateUrl: 'deletionConfirmDialog.html',
            title : title,
            textContent : cont,
            ok : 'Confirm',
            cancel: 'Cancel'
        })).then(function() {
             console.log('confirmed');
             //to be completed
deferred.resolve();
        }, function() {
             console.log('abort');
             //to be completed
deferred.reject();
        });

return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

Your html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in serv" ng-model="item.active">
      <md-checkbox ng-checked="tempFlag" id="{{item.id}}" aria-label="check" type="checkbox"ng-model="item.attivo" ng-change="changeFunc()">
 </div>
```

Then in your controller:

```
    if($scope.item.attivo)
      $scope.tempFlag = true
    else
      $scope.tempFlag = false;

    $scope.changeFunc = function() {
    dialog.deletionConfirmDialog('some title', 'some content').then(accept, reject)

    function accept() {
      $scope.tempFlag = !$scope.tempFlag;
    };

    function reject() {
     $scope.item.attivo = !$scope.item.attivo;
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<input onchange="myFunction()" type="checkbox" id="myCheck">
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("You unchecked the box!");
}
</script>
```

You could also use an onclick event for the confirmation button that will say which boxes are unchecked and tell the user to review their selections.